# Task Scheduler custom trigger - start when EventID is FOO and EventData.Data is BAR

Tags: xml, windows, xpath, event-log, windows-task-scheduler

I want to Windows Task Scheduler to start a custom task when a special event is logged to Windows Event Log. The event has EventID **6702** and when a data parameter is **MyBackupJob**. Here is my current custom trigger and it does not work:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="VisualSVNServerBackgroundJobs">
    <Select Path="VisualSVNServerBackgroundJobs">
            *[System[(EventID=6702)]] and *[EventData[Data[1]='MyBackupJob']]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

What's wrong?

Here is an example of the event from the log:

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="VisualSVN Background Job Service" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49152">6702</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-05-11T12:53:34.650971500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>4885</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>VisualSVNServerBackgroundJobs</Channel> 
  <Computer>svn1.example.com</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>{516B8AED-C3CF-4221-BC91-10B18BD3A56F}</Data> 
  <Data>MyBackupJob</Data> 
  <Data>{E3831378-33E1-4C8E-BE8A-CF08DB1CB7F0}</Data> 
  <Data>Failed to backup 1 out of 2 repositories.</Data> 
  <Data>00:00:00</Data> 
  <Data>203</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
*[System[(EventID=6702)]] and *[EventData[Data[1]='MyBackupJob']]
```

to

```
//Event[EventData[Data[2]="MyBackupJob"]][System[EventID=6702]]
```

and see if it works.

Comment: @bahrep Based on the sample log you posted, it's definitely `Data[2]`. Out of curiosity, what happens when you split the expression and use only `//Event[EventData[Data[2]="MyBackupJob"]]` or only `[System[EventID=6702]] `?

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, I have to remove `//` from the suggested line.

Comment: I overlooked that the task was actually running. Therefore, your suggestion is correct.